# Render partial with different link_to paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views, renderpartial

I am trying to render a `partial` that displays a list of names (that I created using `:resource :create`) and `link_to` their respective pages.  However, I want to implement this twice such that one list links to the **show pages** and the other links to their **edit pages**.

I would prefer to use one partial to accomplish this because they are exactly identical except for their `url_path`.

footer.html.erb:

```
<!--Show-->
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <b class="icon-eye-open icon-white"></b>
                                <b class="caret"></b>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <%= render current_user.apps %>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

<!--Edit-->
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <b class="icon-wrench icon-white"></b>
                                <b class="caret"></b>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <%= render current_user.apps %>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
```

_app.html.erb:

**Show** should have `app` and
**Edit** should have `edit_app_path(app)` for `link_to`'s second argument

```
<li>
    <%= link_to app.name, app %>
</li>
```

Comment: i don't understand exactly, but if you are rendering partial,in partial form some url path is there you can pass as local from partial use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your partial contains only

```
    <li>
      <%= link_to app.name, app %>
    </li>
```

I would suggest to write it two times as as list without css classes isn't enough for a partial imho.

But if you really want to use a partial you can do it with a local variable in Rails 3 way:

```
    <li>
        <%= link_to @app.name, @path %>
    </li>
```

and

```
    <%= render "shared/apps", :collection => current_user.apps, :locals => {:path=> @app} %>
    <%= render "shared/apps", :collection => current_user.apps, :locals => {:path=> edit_app_path(app)} %>
```